# How can I use module and python on cmd?

Tags: python, module

I am trying to use python and module package on cmd. I could find module directory and start the python program, but the python program opened on cmd did not find the module. I think this problem has occurred because of setting path of module directory is wrong.   this is my sys.path on my python program

['', 'C:\Users\skdbs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\idlelib', 'C:\Users\skdbs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python37.zip', 'C:\Users\skdbs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\DLLs', 'C:\Users\skdbs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib', 'C:\Users\skdbs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32', 'C:\Users\skdbs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages']

and this is what happen in my cmd window

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.523]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\skdbs>cd AppData

C:\Users\skdbs\AppData>cd Local

C:\Users\skdbs\AppData\Local>cd Programs

C:\Users\skdbs\AppData\Local\Programs>cd Python

C:\Users\skdbs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python>cd Python37-32

C:\Users\skdbs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32>set PYTHONPATH = C:\Users\skdbs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\PythonModule

C:\Users\skdbs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32>python
Python 3.7.2 (tags/v3.7.2:9a3ffc0492, Dec 23 2018, 22:20:52) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
'>>> import game
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<'stdin>", line 1, in <'module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'game'
'>>>

(P.S. Thank you for reading my poor english)

Comment: You should paste code non remote images, give us a listing (dir) of the folder, try `import sys` and check what you have in `sys.path`.

Comment: Embed the image directly into your post. Most users aren't going to click on your link.

Comment: I tried to write all the things happened in cmd but some kind of error occurred in this site and couldn't post this question.

Comment: @user10967405 you need to [edit] the question and fix it as requested. Don't hide details in comments.